# Chrome headless download pdf using capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I'm using chrome headless with Selenium (3.14.0) and Capybara (3.8.0) in my Ruby on Rails (5.2.1) project and I have a test which works in Non-headless chrome but not in headless chrome. I'm using the '--headless' flag on google chrome stable version 69.

I've setup my headless chrome with the following and this works for all tests which don't download files.

```
download_path="#{Rails.root}/tmp/downloads"

Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        'download.default_directory' => download_path,
        "download.extensions_to_open" => "applications/pdf",
        'download.directory_upgrade' => true,
        'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
        'plugins.plugins_disabled' => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
      },
      binary: "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome",
      args: %w[headless disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080]
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end
```

I've read that I should be sending a command to selenium chrome driver to allow downloads but I cannot figure out how to do that with my setup.  Here is what I'm trying to get working, but with my setup; (not from my code base);

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

bridge = @driver.send(:bridge)
path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id
bridge.http.call(:post, path, cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                 params: {
                   behavior: 'allow',
                   downloadPath: download_path
                 })
```

How do I access the selenium bridge in my setup so that I can send this http call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to send that manually anymore it was added to selenium as `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Server#download_path=`.  You can set it in your driver registration via the `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` instance

```
...
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
  app,
  browser: :chrome,
  desired_capabilities: caps
).tap { |d| d.browser.download_path = <your download path> }
```

Comment: I wish I could say the same. I can consistently have downloads work when headed, but headless never does. I've tried this along with every other suggestion on the web.

Comment: @RyanSandridge What exactly are you setting for your driver - and what exactly is the link you're clicking on to download.  This is the configuration - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/spec/selenium_spec_chrome.rb#L14 - for Capybaras own test suite which downloads in both headed and headless.

Comment: I am clicking on a link on a remote host. I'm using Capybara for webscraping. Any reason why that makes a difference? It seems so arbitrary to me that it works headed but not headless.

Comment: @RyanSandridge There may be a bug in chromedriver but without details I can't test that -- so if you can't or won't provide actual details then there's not much more I can offer

Comment: set like this outside your register driver:
browser_options.add_preference('plugins.always_open_pdf_externally', true)
browser_options.add_preference(:plugins, always_open_pdf_externally: true)
it works for me